# How to use .NET 3.0 with Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, interop, .net-3.0

My Google-fu is failing me on this question.

I have a coworker who has Visual Studio 2005 on his machine. I have Visual Studio 2008. He wants to open a project I wrote in C# 3.0, and we've gotten that far, but VS2005 barfs on the 3.0 code, like `var`.

He has the 3.0 and 3.5 frameworks installed, as well as the Visual Studio 2005 Extensions for Windows Workflow. What else does he need? Or are we pursuing a lost cause, a wild goose chase spurred by my thinking that I heard this was possible somewhere one time?

Please don't suggest he install VS2008 or the Express edition. That simply isn't possible at this time. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far as I understand it, this isn't possible.  If you weren't using the new C# 3.0 code features, he should be able to work with a project created in VS2008 (and compile it against the 2.0 framework), but I don't think the 2005 compiler is ever going to be able to cope with the new syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate the project file in vs2005 and then update the headers on the files to vs2005 and you are back in business. Have a look at [Rick Strahls Blog](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/122975.aspx) for more details on how its done.

Also worth looking at the project converter in [Visual Studio 2005/2008 Interoperability](http://home.hot.rr.com/graye/Articles/ProjectConverter.htm)

You may also need the Visual Studio 2005 extensions for .Net 3.0 to be installed. [WWF Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=5D61409E-1FA3-48CF-8023-E8F38E709BA6&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

The IDE itself may not support the 3.0 functionality. If you can live without the 3.0 features you can compile to 2.0 which he should be able to run ok.